# How to resolve "TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type ..."

Tags: typescript

Here is the code what I have:

```
class ValueObject<T> {
  getValue(): T {
    throw new Error()
  }
}

type KeyofTypeWhereValueIs<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]

abstract class Model {
  getValueObject<Key extends KeyofTypeWhereValueIs<this, ValueObject<any>>>(key: Key): this[Key] {
    throw new Error()
  }
}

class PostModel extends Model {
  get publishDate(): ValueObject<Date> {
    // [ERROR] TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type ...
    // the type of `key` parameter should be 'publishDate' | 'modifiedDate'
    const publishDate = this.getValueObject('publishDate')

    throw new Error()
  }

  get modifiedDate(): ValueObject<Date> {
    throw new Error()
  }

  get title(): string {
    throw new Error()
  }
}
```

it got a type error at `this.getValueObject('publishDate')` which is surprising me because I can't see any issue with this code, is this a bug of TypeScript?

Comment: It's a limitation of TypeScript.  The polymorphic `this` type is an implicit generic type parameter, and your `KeyofTypeWhereValueIs` is a conditional type.  So `getValueObject()` is a generic conditional type, which the compiler sees as essentially opaque.  See the answer to the linked question for more information.  If you widen `this` to `PostModel` in the inside `getPublishDate()` then things will work; see [here](https://tsplay.dev/mq5RJm).